# Prompt before shutting down EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Is it possible to do a "conditional" shutdown with an EC2 instance such that the shutdown process requests confirmation from any logged on users of the VM instance itself before shutting down?

Our VM instances are started/stopped on a set schedule, and sometimes we get caught in the middle of work by the forced shutdown. It would be great if we could get the shutdown process to prompt inside any active user sessions and give the user a chance to say "no thanks, I'm working right now" to stop the shutdown.

Anyone have any idea if EC2 instances have such a feature, or how something like this might be accomplished?

Comment: How is the "schedule" actually implemented?  If the instance is being stopped (not terminated) then yes, there's probably an effective way... but it depends on how the shutdown is currently being initiated.

Comment: Right now we're doing it using the standard AWS api inside a powershell script, which is in turn scheduled using windows task scheduler.

Comment: Are the instances Windows machines, also?

Comment: Yes, all of the machines that we have scheduled for automatic starts/stops are windows machines.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this would be an awesome feature (and I kind of want it now), but there isn't a way to do this from Amazon's side. When you stop or terminate an instance, the instance never gets a chance to complain - it's much like jerking the power cord.

However, from your comment, "*Our VM instances are started/stopped on a set schedule*", it sounds like you have a script or cronjob running somewhere that uses the AWS API to shut down the instances.

Assuming this, I would recommend following a path like this:

1. Write a client program that will run on each instance that listens for a signal on a certain port.
2. Have your auto-shutdown program send that signal to that port on each instance.
3. The instance checks for logged in users and asks them*
4. If the user replies yes, send a signal back to the main cronjob saying that it's okay to shutdown.
5. Then shut down the instance through the API.

Of course, you can and should handle exceptions (like the user still wanting to work) however you please.

---

<sub>*I don't know how to do this.</sub>

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I'd really like to accomplish it without any additional dependencies on the client machine. I wonder if there's a built in windows utility to prompt and get a response?

Answer (score 0):

By way of introduction of what I'm thinking: on a Linux VM in EC2, if you instruct the system to shutdown and "power off" (for example, `sudo halt`), not only does the machine seem to do what you'd expect, the instance itself actually transitions to the "stopped" state in EC2.

I'm not using Windows in EC2, only Linux, and I don't consider myself a Windows server specialist, but *on the assumption that the same integration of behavior is seen with a Windows instance* in EC2, then I see two seemingly-viable options.

First option: Your scheduled maintenance script, instead of stopping the instances via the EC2 API, could instead instruct the machines to shut themselves down with a remote invocation of the `shutdown` command.

`shutdown /m \\computername /s /t 600 /c "nighty night"`

That would, as I understand it, pop up a warning for any logged in user, who could then optionally cancel the shutdown before the 600 second warning expired:

`shutdown /a`

There may be complications like the way authentication needs to happen or some other Windows quirk that makes this solution problematic, but from my perspective, it seems pretty ideal.  The script could continue trying to stop the machine every hour, or however often, until it discovers that the machine is in fact already in the stopped state.

Second option: You don't want to have dependencies on the instance itself, but if the remote invocation of `shutdown` is trickier than it seems, then Plan B is that you could use the task scheduler on the instance itself to perform the same function -- call the shutdown utility with a timeout so the user has time to abort if needed.  As a fail-safe, you could subsequently still make the API call if the machine isn't down, but do it at a later time, accompanied by an alarm/alert that notifies you that the fallback position was necessary, which would alert you to the possibility that your first-line shutdown system wasn't behaving as expected.

In Linux, of course, this would be easily implemented as a cron job that fired off the `shutdown` command, which broadcasts a warning and can be similarly aborted by a user with sufficient privilege, or by a remote process that connects to the machine via SSH and issues the shutdown command on a schedule.